# Easy php mail form in purchased template does not work correctly

Tags: forms, email

I am a very novice programmer, and usually purchase inexpensive templates to work off of to build websites and teach myself the basics.  In this template for a simple email form, the form does actually send the email as it is supposed to, however, the form does not update with the alert-success or alert-error messages and instead just gives me a blank page when it runs.

Can someone help me out here and tell me what this template is missing to make it work correctly?  I feel like there should be something in the mail.php to handle the errors. I know, it's super basic, but we all have to start somewhere!

The form:

```
<form method="post" class="contact-form" action="mail.php">
        <div id="personal">
          <div class="control-group"><!--name field-->
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="required span9" type="text" name="name" data-fieldid="0" value="Full Name" onclick="if(this.value=='Full Name') this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Full Name'">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group"><!--email field-->
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="required span9" type="email" name="email" data-fieldid="1" value="Your Email" onclick="if(this.value=='Your Email') this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your Email'">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group"><!--message field-->
            <div class="controls">
              <textarea name="message" rows="12" class="required span9" data-fieldid="2" onclick="if(this.value=='Type Message') this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Type Message'">Message</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls right">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-main">Send <i class="fa fa-send" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notifications">
          <div id="contactFormSent" class="formSent alert alert-success"> <strong>Your Message Has Been Sent!</strong> Thank you for contacting us.</div>
          <div id="contactFormError" class="formError alert alert-error"> <strong>Oops, An error has occurred!</strong> See the marked fields above to fix the errors.</div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

The mail.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
//  Change your email here
        $mailTo = "info@astortowerofficial.com";
        $subject = "Astor Tower Contact Form";
        $body = "New message from web
<br><br>
FROM: ".$_POST['email']."<br>
NAME: ".$_POST['name']."<br>
COMMENTS: ".$_POST['message']."<br>";   
        $headers = "To: Elegance <".$mailTo.">\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
        //send email
        $mail_success =  mail($mailTo, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($body), $headers);        
}
?>
```

*edited to take out un-needed CSS.

Any help or direction appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Paste this to your mail.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // Change your email here
    $mailTo = "info@astortowerofficial.com";
    $subject = "Astor Tower Contact Form";
    $body = "New message from web
    <br><br>
    FROM: " . $_POST['email'] . "<br>
    NAME: " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>
    COMMENTS: " . $_POST['message'] . "<br>";
    $headers = "To: Elegance <" . $mailTo . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $_POST['name'] . " <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";

    // Send email
    $mail_success = mail($mailTo, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($body), $headers);

    if ($mail_success) {
        // If mail is sent successfully, return success message
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Your message has been sent. Thank you for contacting us.'));
    } else {
        // If mail fails to send, return error message
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'An error occurred while sending the message.'));
    }
}
?>
```

Now you need to update the form submission handling in the HTML file to process the response from mail.php and display the appropriate success or error message. This should go to your contact.php file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contact-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'success') {
                    $('#contactFormSent').text(response.message).show();
                    $('#contactFormError').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#contactFormError').text(response.message).show();
                    $('#contactFormSent').hide();
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#contactFormError').text('An error occurred while sending the message.').show();
                $('#contactFormSent').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the form should now handle the success and error messages properly when submitting the email.

To display the success or error messages on the same page when the form is submitted, you can update the JavaScript code to show the messages within the notifications div. Here's how you can modify the JavaScript code to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contact-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'success') {
                    $('.notifications').html('<div id="contactFormSent" class="formSent alert alert-success"><strong>Your Message Has Been Sent!</strong> ' + response.message + '</div>');
                } else {
                    $('.notifications').html('<div id="contactFormError" class="formError alert alert-error"><strong>Oops, An error has occurred!</strong> ' + response.message + '</div>');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                $('.notifications').html('<div id="contactFormError" class="formError alert alert-error"><strong>An error occurred while sending the message.</strong></div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Where in the HTML file do I put for submission handling?

Comment: @TiffanyGilbertThomas  contact.php , you can paste your code there , I have edited my answer for you. 
Good luck

Comment: I don't have a contact.php file in the template, so I should create one?  I don't see where it would get called in the form.  Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: just make contact.html and paste the code in it

Comment: paste it on the same form file , edit it and paste the code in there it will work

Comment: Thank you very much - this does work, however I would like the callback to trigger this part of the form so that it will show on the page instead of just putting the success on a separate page?

--------
<div class="notifications">
          <div id="contactFormSent" class="formSent alert alert-success"> <strong>Your Message Has Been Sent!</strong> Thank you for contacting us.</div>
          <div id="contactFormError" class="formError alert alert-error"> <strong>Oops, An error has occurred!</strong> See the marked fields above to fix the errors.</div>
        </div>
-------

Comment: That's another question btw, I have edited my answer for you to achieve this 
hope it helps

Comment: @TiffanyGilbertThomas you can use CSS to style that or just write <style> </style> with in the same page to change color for div id or make classes , its your choice